# Thermometer Gauge with ScalingFunctions Broken?

Tags: dynamic

Is this broken? The following generates an error:

```
ThermometerGauge[Dynamic[t], {1, 100}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log10"]
```

Comment: Yep, hard to argue. Please report it to WRI Support.